# Play 2.0's equivalent for J2EE's request.setAttribute(key, val)?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been searching Http.Request object - but not sure if it is the right object to use for storing the attributes across sessions. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Framework is stateless so it doesn't have *session* in the traditional sense.  But you can use cookies and Play's wrapper around cookies, called *session*.   More details: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaSessionFlash